# Convert item to bucket in C# code

Tags: buckets, unit-testing

We have a code in our solution that checks if the item is a bucket using

`Sitecore.Buckets.Managers.BucketManager.IsBucket(bucketItem)`

I'm creating a unit test using fakeDb and my code is this

```
var bucketId = Sitecore.Data.ID.NewID;

using (var db = new Db {    
     new DbItem("Bucket", bucketId)
})

var bucketItem = db.GetItem(bucketId);

bucketItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
bucketItem[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.BucketableField] = "1";
bucketItem[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket] = "1";
bucketItem.Editing.EndEdit();

if (BucketManager.IsBucket(bucketItem))
{
     //DO STUFF HERE WHEN ITEM IS BUCKET
}
```

The IF statement is returning false. How do I convert the item to be a bucket in C# code?

Comment: what is the value of `bucketItem[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket]` after your `bucketItem.Editing.EndEdit()` ?

Comment: Why are you unit testing the framework anyway?

Comment: We created a custom pipeline code to use displayname of the items under a bucket. So we need to identify if a bucket item was used based only from the url

Answer (score 1):

This code should be enough:

```
var bucketItem = db.GetItem(bucketId);

bucketItem.Editing.BeginEdit();
bucketItem[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket] = "1";
bucketItem.Editing.EndEdit();
```

You don't need to set `BucketableField` to `"1"`;

The reason why your test doesn't work is that when you call `BucketManager.IsBucket` it calls

```
BucketManager.Provider.IsBucket(item)
```

The problem now is that `BucketManager.Provider` is read from the config, which must be missing when your test is running. That's why `BucketManager` uses `NullBucketProvider` as a fallback when nothing is configured and `NullBucketProvider.IsBucket(item)` returns always `false`.

Comment: Thanks for this, but do you know how to make this return true?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you with that. But you can just use `if (MainUtil.GetBool(bucketItem[Sitecore.Buckets.Util.Constants.IsBucket], false))` and don't waste your time on `BucketManager`